# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Unable to access data in text widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am new to flutter. I am making an app which shows current time of the given/specified location. I want to access data using routing but this is error i got:

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

The code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Map data = {} ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    print(data);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
                label: Text('Edit Location'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    data['loaction']
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data coming from `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments` can be null and you cannot use map operators on null value, so the initial fix can be: replace `data['loaction']` with `data ?? this.data['location']` and `Map data = {}` with `Map data = {'location': 'initial value'};` and try